# entry control with asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

so i wanna do an entry control in my controller but it doesn't work !! so i putted them in comments.

this is my controller method :

```js
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
        {
            Projet projet = new Projet();
            projet.UtilisateurID = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["x"].ToString());
            //var x = (from p in db.Projets where (p.nomP.Equals(form["nom"])) select p).FirstOrDefault();
            //if (x != null)
            //    ViewBag
            //else 
            projet.nomP = form["nom"];
            projet.DateDebut = Convert.ToDateTime(form["DateDebut"]);
            projet.DateFinPrevue = Convert.ToDateTime(form["DateFinPrevue"]);
            //if (!form["DateFinReele"].Equals("")) 
            //{
            //    projet.DateFinReele = Convert.ToDateTime(form["DateFinReele"]);
            //};
            projet.DateFinReele = Convert.ToDateTime(form["DateFinReele"]);
            projet.Description = form["Description"];
            projet.etat = form["etat"];
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Projets.Add(projet);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            };
            return View(projet);
        }
```

and this is my view :

```html
@model mvc_depences.Models.Projet
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/admin.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Projet", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <br />
        <legend class="legend">Ajouter Un Nouveau Projet</legend>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="cke_label" for="NomP">Nom</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom Projet" data-val="true" required="" data-val-length="Taille max  est 50 caracteres !! " data-val-length-max="50" id="nom" name="nom">
                                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="nom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <!--Date Debut !!-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="DateDebut">Date Debut</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                        <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                            <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateDebut must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateDebut est requis." id="DateDebut" name="DateDebut" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateDebut_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateDebut_dateview">
                                                <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <script>
                                        jQuery(function () {
                                            jQuery("#DateDebut").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateDebut" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <!--Date fin Prevue !!-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinPrevue">Date Fin Prevue</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                        <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                            <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateFinPrevue must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinPrevue est requis." id="DateFinPrevue" name="DateFinPrevue" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinPrevue_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinPrevue_dateview">
                                                <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <script>
                                        jQuery(function () {
                                            jQuery("#DateFinPrevue").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateFinPrevue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <!--Date fin Reele !!-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinReele">Date Fin Reele</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                        <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                            <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateFinReele must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinReele est requis." id="DateFinReele" name="DateFinReele" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinReele_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinReele_dateview">
                                                <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <script>
                                        jQuery(function () {
                                            jQuery("#DateFinReele").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateFinReele" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="Description">Description</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <textarea rows="6" cols="35" id="Description" name="Description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="etat">Etat</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div align="justify">
                                        <br>
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.etat, "En Cours", new { @checked = true })
                                        <label class="En_Cours" for="En_Cours"> En Cours</label>
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.etat, "Termine")
                                        <label class="En_Cours" for="En_Cours">Terminé</label>
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.etat, "Annule")
                                        <label class="En_Cours" for="En_Cours"> Annulé</label>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-left:400px;margin-top:120px">
                                <div class="col-md-12" style="width:350px">
                                    <input id="Submit" class="btn btn-default" name="actionType" type="submit" value="Engeristrer" style="width:150px" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

some of my controls should be done in the controller like the "nomP" because i should do a select from the database and some others i can do them in the view (i don't need a database access) 
so haw can i do it ?
ps : even with the "required" annotation it doesn't work
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the point of `if (ModelState.IsValid)` - your not binding to a model so it will always be valid.

Comment: my instance of model is "projet"  ! and if i leave a field empty it shows me an exception , so it's not alaways valid ..

Comment: Yes, because `ModelState` is **always** valid so you saving data even if the model is invalid. (using `FormCollection` does not add anything to `ModelState`)

Comment: so how can i do a control in this case ?

Comment: Go to the MVC site and learn the basics. In particular how to use the strongly typed HtmlHelper methods to generate you view based on your model properties and how to post back you model (never use `FormCollection`)

Comment: i know that using  formcollection it's not a good programming way , but i was obliged to use it so i can't change my code ... it's the only solution for my case